# search in div with group of li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<div>` with group of `<li>` elements and I want to filter the elements. Suppose there are 1 to 10 `<li>` elements. If I enter 5 in the search box the `<div>` should show only 5. When I remove the number 5 it should show all `<li>` elements.

```
<input type="text">
  <div>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li‌​>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
  </div>
```

Comment: Post your codes, This is not _odesk_ least you could so is to post valid HTML.

Comment: How do you determine which five to show? Is it the first five? The last five or a random selection of the five?

Comment: That is very easy but you need to paste your code.

Comment: <input type="text"><div><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li></div>.if 5 in search box it should show<div><li>5</li></div>

Comment: and what about li elements?

Comment: @AmaraBalakrishna  edit your post. Paste your code in there.

Comment: On key press event of your textbox, copy all your li elements from that div to a new hidden div(display: none).  After that clear all li from your existing div and loop through the li from hidden div and populate your existing div till the counter reaches 0.

Comment: First off, for basic formatting, you should wrap your list items in an actual list element (ol for ordered, ul for unordered)

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.text').keyup(function(){
       if( $(this).val()!= ''){  
            var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $('.number li').each(function(){               
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            (text.indexOf(valThis) !== -1) ? $(this).contents().get(0).nodeValue : $(this).hide(); 
         });       
         }else{
            $('.number li').show();       
         }   

     }); 
    });
    /*-------------- Html ----------------- */
   <div class="number">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li> 
        <li>2</li> 
        <li>3</li> 
        <li>4</li>  
        <li>5</li>     
        <li>6</li> 
        <li>7</li> 
        <li>8</li> 
        <li>9</li> 
        <li>10</li>  
    </ul>
</div>
<input name="" class="text" type="text" />
```

Comment: if i use hide the height of div is remains same i want height should reduce

Comment: @AmaraBalakrishna you can easily change div height in the function Like this $("div.number").css("height","20px");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what are you working because your explanation doesn't provide too much info, but maybe is better if you use a table instead of a list and dataTables jquery pluging which has a live search of the table content

Answer (score 0):

While creating the li create the id with the no's like **testLi_1, testLi_2 .....**.
And create the element with same class **testLi**.

By default show all the li by

```
$('.testLi').show();
```

When user enters the value create a for loop and iterate the element and display in below way

```
var userInput = $("inputId").value(); //User Enter value 
for(var i=1; i<= userInput ; i++){
   $('#testLi_'+i).show();
}
```

Comment: this will be invoked whenever user change enter the no of li to be displayed. But before that we have to put a check for user Input.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').keyup( function(){
    if($(this).val() == ''){
        $('li').css('display', 'visible')
    } else {
        $('li').css('display', 'none')
        $('li:eq('+($(this).val()-1)+')').css('display', 'visible')
    }
});

<!-- html -->
<input type="text">
    <div>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
<input type="text" id='text1' onblur="myFunction()">
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var txt =$("#text1").val();
$("ul li").each(function(){
if(txt.length>0){   
 if($(this).html() == txt){
  $(this).show();
 }else{
  $(this).hide();
 }
}else{
$(this).show();
}
});
}
</script>
```